# How do I build a jar file from Selenium Java automation project using IntelliJ

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I have created an automation project using Selenium Java through IntelliJ. Build tool is maven and framework is TestNG. I want to convert it into a single jar file which can be passed onto to other users for execution.
I referred various forums explaining usage of example at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html?_ga=2.157243451.1413470517.1581811713-2023866472.1581811713#

[Artefact creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJvMa.png)

The problem I face is, there is no main class in my Selenium Java project. What do I select in "Main Class field"
Below is snapshot of my project:
[Automation Project snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXGOT.png)

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend to use this application? If you want to run it as a java file - it must contain the main method. Otherwise you use it as a library jar which you place into another's application classpath.

Comment: Its an automation project that tests a website.. I intend to run it through command prompt.